# why resultant(after running html/css code) box sizes are different for div and a tag when applied the same set of properties?

Tags: html, css

```css
div, a {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>This is a div tag</div>
<a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

I expected to get the same size of boxes but found different ones.

Comment: divs are display block by default but anchors are display inline by default. Add **a{display:block}** so you can control the anchor

Comment: Inline elements like `a` don't accept `height` or `width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display: block;` to your CSS.

Like this:

```css
div, a {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

Comment: While this creates the expected result, it does not explain the problem. OP in my understanding is asking for an explanation rather than a solution.